# Why is this not a logarithmic branch point?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

Good afternoon!

I wanted to ask a quick question, as a beginner in complex analysis, I am trying to get my head around branch points. I came upon [some lecture notes](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.04/Notes/Branch_Points_B_Cuts.pdf), but then did not understand something.

The notes define (page 4) that a branch point is a point such that the function does not return to its original value, as you go around a sufficiently small closed curve around it. To motivate that definition, it shows the following example page 3:

[image]

And it says that if you go around the first path, the $\log$ function ($z \mapsto \log|z| + i*\arg(z)$) is multi-valued (unless you introduce a branch cut), but that, if you go around the second path, it returns to its original value.

And I don't understand why that is so. Because, in the second case, $z = re^{i\theta}$, exactly as in the first one, so why would a full rotation come back to the same value in one case and not in the other? I don't see any mention of introducing a principal value to the argument or anything; so I don't understand what's so fundamentally different between those two examples.

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: In the second case, the argument is always in the first quadrant.  How big can $\theta_0$ be?

Comment: Oh, I get your point, I was not looking at $\theta_0$ the right way! Thanks for your answer :D

Comment: Hi! Me again. As I went on with the notes, I came upon another problem and thought I'd ask it here so as not to create another post. Is there a characterization of branch points that allows us to "reduce the number of values to try"? Like, I read that for $z \mapsto \log(z^2 - 1)$, we only have to check the poles and zeroes of the argument (so $\pm 1$ and $\infty$). Is this a general property? I've tried to find some general properties justifying this "shortcut", but could not find anything but specific examples. If you would have an idea, I'd be grateful! :)

Comment: Actually, by the rules of the site, you shouldn't ask new questions in comments, because they'll be hard for other people to find.  However, you have to check the zeroes and the *singularities*.  It's just that the composition of analytic functions is analytic.